# Search Function asp.net SQL Server 2008 and fixed time

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a question :

I want to make a search function in my asp.net project ! I'm using SQL Server 2008 database.

I have a gridview on my page showing something like this: `Name,Age,ID`.

How can I make a search function to show the entire line of tables for the term searched?

If I search the ID code, it will show the entire line with `name,age,id`.

I couldn't find a way to do that.

Also

I would like to know how can I make a fixed time for SQL Server database? I don't want to get pc time / date because it can be changed.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "show the entire line of tables for the term searhed"?  Do you mean the entire record from a table that had that search term?  Do you intend to search more than one table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to search using tsql:

```
SELECT Name, Age, ID FROM YourTableName
WHERE Name = YourSearchTerm
OR Age = YourSearchTerm
OR ID = YourSearchTerm
```

To get the time of your sql database you would use the following:

```
SELECT getdate()
```

This gets the time of the server that the database is sitting on.

If this doesn't answer your question, please provide more details and specifics.

Comment: I have a table called : INFO with 3 columns Name,Age,ID on a gridview , if I search the ID , I want to get the name,age and the id of the term searched . For example : George,22,5 , if I search 5 it will show George,22,5 , where george=name,22=age,5=id

Comment: @FallenNoob - The above example will provide the database record that you are looking for (of course replacing YourSearchTerm with '5') but I have a feeling that you are trying to look at this from a different perspective.  There are many ways to accomplish the same goal, so by saying you want to 'search' and 'return' a record is really vague.

Answer (score 0):

http://evonet.com.au/creating-a-great-looking-gridview-with-filtering/

I think this is what you are looking for.